# Converting date Jan-12 2015 10:51AM to Date format for Sharepoint use

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, text-formatting

I have a date that imports into Excel from an external source as Jan-12 2015 10:51AM, but is not a friendly date format for coping into Sharepoint 2013 datasheet. How do I convert this in Excel so we can easily load date field into SharePoint?

Comment: In Excel when you click on the cell holding the data what appears in the formula bar? This will make it a little clearer the difference between how Excel is displaying the date and how it is storing it.

Comment: JAN-12 2015 10:51AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to turn the string into a date with a formula like:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,2)&"-"&LEFT(A1,3)&"-"&MID(A1,8,4))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,13,5))
```

The cell the formula goes into may need to have all references to `A1` set to the proper target cell and be formatted to show date with time.

The formula rearranges the string in an order that `DATEVALUE` can parse and then adds the time from `TIMEVALUE`. `MID(A1,5,2)` gets the date, `LEFT(A1,3)` gets the month, and `MID(A1,8,4)` gets the year.

All of this depends on the cell `A1` having exactly the same spacing for every instance.

Depending on your needs you can either leave this as a formula or copy and paste as values before loading into SharePoint.

Edit: on reflection the `TIMEVALUE` portion should be dropped from the formula unless an if statement is added to handle the difference between `AM` and `PM`.

Comment: This of course works.  But as times values and dates will come out with for example JAN-9 2015 11:05PM, a simple shift of the date will mess this up.  I was looking fo ran easier fix.

Comment: If the day portion of the string is variable length it is still possible to write a formula to handle that, but it does get complex. Perhaps looking at ways to modify the datasource that is being imported into Excel is an option?